I'm trying to implement the Web Share Api functionality on my web app but when i test it on my iphone 14 on chrome, is not working
Has anyone had the same issue? I'm implementing the Web Share API and it works when I tested it using my desktop but when I tested it using my iPhone 14 it works on Safari but when I use Chrome, the first couple of times I click on the share button it does not work, some times it works and some times it does not so I need to spam click it hoping it works one of those times, what is also wierd is that when i used an online virtual machine and tested it on iphone12 it worked fine so i don't know if it is a compatibility problem ?
handleCopyOpen = async (socialHandle) => {
      if (this.sharingInProgress) {
        console.log('Sharing is already in progress.');
        return;
      }
      this.sharingInProgress = true;
    
      try {
        const targetElement = document.querySelector('.milestone-popup');
        if (!targetElement) throw new Error('Target element not found.');
    
        // Get the Blob from the prepareScreenshot function
        const blob = await this.prepareScreenshot(targetElement);
    
        if (navigator.canShare && navigator.canShare({ files: [new File([blob], 'screenshot.png', { type: 'image/png' })] })) {
          const file = new File([blob], 'screenshot.png', { type: 'image/png' });
    
          await navigator.share({
            title: 'Achievement on Fanstories',
            text: 'Check out my latest achievement!',
            files: [file],
          });
          console.log('Shared successfully using Web Share API');
        } else {
          console.warn('Web Share API not supported. Showing fallback.');
          const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          window.open(url, '_blank');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.name === 'AbortError') {
          console.log('User canceled the share operation.');
        } else {
          console.error('Error during sharing:', error);
          alert('Failed to share. Please try again.');
        }
      } finally {
        this.sharingInProgress = false;
      }
    };
    
    prepareScreenshot = async (targetElement) => {
      // Define cloneContainer outside the try block for broader scope
      let cloneContainer;
    
      try {
        // Clone the target element to avoid modifying the original DOM
        cloneContainer = document.createElement('div');
        cloneContainer.style.cssText = `
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          width: 100vw;
          height: 100vh;
          z-index: -1; /* Keeps the clone invisible */
          opacity: 0; /* Ensures it's not visible to users */
        `;
        document.body.appendChild(cloneContainer);
    
        const clonedElement = targetElement.cloneNode(true);
        cloneContainer.appendChild(clonedElement);
    
        // Adjust cloned content for capturing
        const footerElement = clonedElement.querySelector('.share-footer');
        const closeButtonElement = clonedElement.querySelector('.close-button');
        const confettiCanvas = clonedElement.querySelector('canvas');
    
        if (footerElement) footerElement.style.display = 'none';
        if (closeButtonElement) closeButtonElement.style.display = 'none';
        if (confettiCanvas) confettiCanvas.style.display = 'none';
    
        // Allow DOM changes to reflect
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
    
        // Capture the screenshot
        const canvas = await html2canvas(clonedElement, {
          backgroundColor: null,
          useCORS: true,
          scale: 2, // High resolution
        });
    
        // Convert canvas to Blob
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          canvas.toBlob(
            (blob) => {
              if (blob) {
                resolve(blob); // Return the Blob directly
              } else {
                reject(new Error('Failed to convert canvas to Blob.'));
      

        }
        },
        'image/png', // MIME type
        1.0 // Image quality (1.0 = best)
      );
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during screenshot preparation:', error);
    throw error;
  } finally {
    // Ensure cloneContainer is cleaned up
    if (cloneContainer) {
      document.body.removeChild(cloneContainer);
    }
  }
};

